# netfonds.no - High Frequency Data

Tags: high-frequency, historical-data, tick-data, data-source

I originally got the idea from [Python for Finance](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920032441.do). But there are nomerous other examples on how to get high [Netfonds](http://hopey.netfonds.no/market.php) ([here](https://github.com/hamiltonkibbe/stocks/blob/master/sources/netfonds.py) and [here](https://github.com/pcawthron/Python/blob/master/TA-Lib/Netfonds%20Example/NetFonds%20Data%20Fetch.py)).

They don't seem to work any more:

http://hopey.netfonds.no/posdump.php?date=20121130&paper=GOOG.O&csv_format=csv

seems to yield nothing. Has anyone successfully scraped data from them? Are there other free sources?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did not know this provider, but had a look.

- for daily data, the url seems to be http://www.netfonds.no/quotes/paperhistory.php?paper=GOOG.O&csv_format=txt
- for market depth: http://www.netfonds.no/quotes/posdump.php?date=20160303&paper=E-SABL.BTSE&csv_format=txt
- for intraday trades: http://www.netfonds.no/quotes/tradedump.php?paper=E-SABL.BTSE&csv_format=txt

the timestamps seems to be at the second only...